# How do I set CSS3 flex-basis property using Bootstrap Flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using CSS3 I can individually set the flex properties like so

```
.someclass {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;   
}
```

Using Bootstrap (version >= 4.1) flex it seems I can only set [flex-grow-X and flex-shrink-X](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink), like so

```
<div class="someclass flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1">...</div>
```

Is there are way to set the flex-basis using bootstrap 4.1?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: you have all the `col-*` that do this.

Comment: @Paulie_D This question is more out of interest, than a specific problem.

Comment: `class="col-12 px-0"` gives you the `flex-basis: 100%` with a few other width properties set

Answer (score 14):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css) of Bootstrap v4.1, there are no utility classes included that specifically target the `flex-basis` value.

Searching through the [file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css), there are only 12 occurances of the word `flex-basis`:

- 5 times to set `flex-basis` to `0` for some of the `col-*` classes (e.g. [line 625](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/3b558734382ce58b51e5fc676453bfd53bba9201/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L625)).
- 7 times for styling specific `navbar` related classes (e.g. [line 4268](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/3b558734382ce58b51e5fc676453bfd53bba9201/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L4268)).

This also seem to remain the case in the latest versions of Bootstrap at the time of this writing:

- [Bootstrap v4.5.3](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css)
- [Bootstrap v5.0.0-alpha3](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v5.0.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.css)